# Is there an official API to parse SQL LocalDB connection strings?

Tags: .net, sql-server, localdb

The standard .NET `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is unaware of two "properties" that are specific to SQL LocalDB:

- `IsLocalDb`
- `InstanceName`

e.g. I want the following connection string `(localdb)\MyInstance` to resolve `IsLocalDb = true`, and `InstanceName = MyInstance`.

Is there an official/supported way to parse these SQL LocalDB-specific connection strings?

Answer (score 0):

There are no connection string keys with these names, where do you see that in use?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

You should be able to parse the "Data Source" value and get the same information, alternatively you can get the information from a open SqlConnection with the following SQL statements

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsLocalDB')
```

and

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')
```

Comment: They aren't connection string keys. This is my 'imagining' of an API that can parse SQL LocalDB DataSource strings into meaningful properties

Comment: It does not exist, and the way to get them is via the "SERVERPROPERTY" calls